# Java Script functionality not working in firefox on linux

Tags: firefox, javascript

I have developed a project in asp.net which contains javascript functionality as well. The application is working as expected in windows with all the browsers. But I am facing issues with linux OS. Wherever the javascript has been added,  that functionality will not work. I am not receiving any error as well. Kindly help me as soon as possible to sort this out as this is very urgent.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the webpage publicly available, so that we can test it as well?

Comment: Try opening the Error Console (`Tools` -> `Web Developer` -> `Error Console`).  Are there any relevant errors reported for the pages you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you have **enabled** Javascript in Firefox. You can check that setting in one of following ways:

**A.** From Firefox menu go to :

**Edit** > **Preferences** > **Select "Content" tab**

Default (and preferable) settings would be

[image]

**B.** Using `about:config`

Enter `about:config` in address bar and then type `javascript` in the *filter* section. The preference name "javascript.enabled" should have **true** as its value. If you are not clear look at following screenshot.

[image]

If you have above-mentioned settings as they are (i.e. in their default configuration), make sure you have **NOT** enable any script blocking Add-ons (like "No Script") to Firefox.

Comment: [OPTIONAL]
You can install `Firebug` Add-on to see whether there are any errors while delivering web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the options of firefox? I have a localized, german menu, so I can't tell you the original names - maybe it is a bit different:

In the 2nd menu, last entry 'settings', a dialog pops up. The 3rd section 'content' shows some option boxes, among them 'enable javascript'. Is it checked?

Another approach: In the addressbar, enter

```
about:config
```

confirm, and in the searchbox below enter

```
 javascript
```

What does it say? Something suspicious?

Comment: Ya its checked and have enabled pop-up also.

Comment: I checked this and still its not working.

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards: Having Javascript disabled **can** be the reason for Javascript not working, so while it isn't the answer to Chaitra's problem, it might be for other ones, which find the question, searching for a similar problem.